# Reverse rows in a matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

To rotate a matrix 180 degrees around the center point, what I am planning to do is first transverse the matrix, then reverse the rows and then do it again to produce the final result.

This works and I can do it step by step, but how would I mathematically represent the second step (switching the rows) as a matrix? as in:

```
[2,1] * reversing matrix = [1,2]
[1,0]                      [0,1]
```

Comment: (switching the *columns*)?

Comment: It might be better if you had distinct values in each position so your operation is unambiguous.

Comment: yeah switching the columns, thats what I was looking for...

it seems to work if I multiply the matrix by 
  [0,1]
  [1,0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $$P=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{array}\right],$$ we have $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}a & b\\c & d\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}d & c\\b & a\end{array}\right].$$ Multiplication by on the right by $P$ swaps the columns of a $2\times 2$ matrix, and multiplication on the left by $P$ swaps the rows of a $2\times 2$ matrix. Doing both gives the end result of a $180^\circ$ rotation of the entries.

Comment: Nice, thankyou for your help.
Is there any way of merging that into one matrix?
ie A*P = [d,c_b,a]?

Comment: @TaylorDale: There isn't, unfortunately. If there were a $2\times 2$ matrix $Q$ such that $AQ=PAP$ for all $2\times 2$ matrices $A$, then in particular, if $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix, then $Q=IQ=PIP=PP=I.$ But $I$ doesn't do what you want to general $2\times 2$ matrices--in fact, it only does what you want to $2\times 2$ matrices that are symmetric across both diagonals.

Comment: Is this possible for 3x2 matrix?

Comment: @StephenJacob Yes. Rather than using the same matrix on the left and right, though, we'll need a $3\times 3$ matrix and a $2\times 2$ matrix. The idea is the same, though.

Comment: @CameronBuie Though I have learned matrix in high school, I never understood the purpose until I came across programming. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
[1 2] [0 1]  =  [2 1] 
[3 4] [1 0]     [4 3]
```

Comment: ah! thankyou, i got that just as you posted it :/

So is there any special term for this or is it just an identity matrix?

Comment: The matrix [0,1 ; 1,0] is called a permutation matrix. You can make any permutation to columns multiplying on the right. On the left you make permutations of rows.

Comment: Ok :) so is there a way to represent the permutation matrix as you do with the identity matrix by, looking something like:
IA = A
(where a is my matrix?)